# Oracle19C installation is stuck at executing datapatch in Windows 10 using dbca

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-19c

I tried using dbca. There are no errors. It just hangs. I tried leaving it running for 4 hours. It is always stuck at 36% even after multiple tries.

**Logs:**

[progressPage.flowWorker] [ 2020-05-25 00:26:04.206 IST ] [CloneDBCreationStep.executeImpl:823]  executing datapatch %ORACLE_HOME%\OPatch\datapatch.bat

Comment: What did oracle support say?

Comment: Are you running any kind of anti-virus software?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user installing the software is in the local ora_dba group, and that os authentication is enabled in sqlnet.ora:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

Also, it is a good idea to make sure that any anti-virus software doing active scanning is disabled during install/db create activity, and that when running it contains exceptions for all Oracle-related files and directories.

Comment: sqlnet.ora has SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS). Defender was also turned off. In the end instead of creating database I generated scripts for database creation and executed them.